# using Mac OSX "open" command to open URL with -n flag

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I'm having trouble getting /usr/bin/open to open a browser to a specific URL when using the -n flag.

For example, this will work:

```
open -a "Google Chrome" "https://stackoverflow.com"
```

...successfully opening the desired page. However, if my browser is already open, it will open it in an existing window as a tab. The man page for open says this should be remedied with the -n flag, but:

```
open -n -a "Google Chrome" "https://stackoverflow.com"
```

...opens a new instance (window) of my browser to the homepage without navigating to the desired URL.

I've also tried moving around the -n flag in the command and messing with other flags (such as -F).

environment: macOS Sierra 10.12.6

UPDATE: Here are some other solutions I've tried...

I've tried adding --args before the URL. This makes it behave like the first command above, essentially ignoring the -n flag....

```
open -n -a "Google Chrome" --args "https://stackoverflow.com"
```

...will open the desired URL, but again in a tab and not a new window.

I've tried making '--new-window' an option for --args:

```
open -a "Google Chrome" --args '--new-window' "https://stackoverflow.com"
```

...this behaves the same way as the -n flag, opening a new window but not passing it a URL.

I've also tried putting the URL before the --args:

```
open -n -a "Google Chrome" "https://stackoverflow.com" --args '--new-window'
```

...this behaves as if I did not put the --args flag, opening the URL in another tab.

Comment: `-n` doesn't just open a new window; it creates an entirely *new* process running Chrome (independent of whatever Chrome would ordinarily do to open a new window). The problem you describe, though, seems to be specific to Chrome (or at least independent of `open`); `open -n -a Safari $URL` works as you want.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that `open` isn't meant to be a full-blown scripting app; it's a programmatic double-click with a few other ad-hoc features tacked on.

Comment: Weird - I'm seeing Safari behave the same way as Chrome.

Comment: Is there another solution I should be using that is relatively comparable to open in brevity but more robust? Maybe I just need to execute an AppleScript for this one little feature.

Comment: AppleScript would probably be the right thing to use, but I don't know how scriptable Chrome actually is.

Answer (score 13):

This works on my OSX El Capitan. The `--new-window` is a chrome argument, a list of which can be viewed [here](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)

```
open -n -a "Google Chrome" --args "--new-window" "https://stackoverflow.com"
```

Comment: It's odd that `--new-window` is required if you are starting a new process, rather than trying to send a command to an existing process.

Comment: @chepner True. I think it has something to do with the fact that chrome tabs are already separate processes.

Comment: You can also pass multiple '--new-window' flags & values for opening more than one tab:

```open -n -a "Google Chrome" --args "--new-window" "https://stackoverflow.com"  "--new-window" "https://google.com"```

Answer (score 4):

After much trial and error, I've found that this is indeed possible and that it can be done in two ways:

...passing the -n flag to open and the --new-window arg to Google Chrome:

```
open -n -a "Google Chrome" --args '--new-window' "https://stackoverflow.com"
```

...ordering the parameters correctly such that the --args flag comes after the URL param (note that the -n flag passed to open will break this):

```
open -a "Google Chrome" "https://stackoverflow.com" --args '--new-window'
```

These open a new window with the specified URL.

Answer (score 1):

The `-n` command will start a new instance for your browser – by default, it will open in a new tab in your browser. Do so with the following command:

```
open -n https://stackoverflow.com
```

If you want to open in a new ***window***, you must specify so (but must also specify which browser):

```
open -n -a Google\ Chrome https://stackoverflow.com
```

***Note**: for those new to bash commands: the backslash in `Google\ Chrome` is an escaped space --> spaces aren't recognized in bash commands (they're used to identify arguments in commands...).*